# ¿Qué quiere decir “peinarse con la raya a la derecha”?

Tags: significado

En un [artículo sobre el ciclista español](http://deportes.elpais.com/deportes/2015/05/26/actualidad/1432649737_519618.html), Alberto Contador, en el Giro de Italia, El País utilizó la frase:

> Alberto Contador ha empezado a peinarse con la raya a la derecha.

Buscando un poco en el internet, encontré un artículo sobre [lenguage corporal](http://lenguajecorporal.org/teoria-raya-cabello/) que sugiere que las personas que tengan el cabello con la raya a la izquierda son vistas como más sinceras y exitosas.

Ayer Contador tuvo un pinchazo, que le costó por lo menos 30 segundos, pero después, no sólo atrapó, sino pasó, el hombre que era segunda en la carrera y en una de las subidas más brutales conocidas en el ciclismo. Así que, supongo que raya a la izquierda no puede significar lo contrario de exitoso o fiable.

Adivinando, voy con poco convencional o atrevido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es ninguna expresión, al menos no en España. En todo caso, en el artículo que comentas el periodista empieza hablando sobre los lados izquierdo y derecho del cerebro y sus simbologías (derecho -> racional, izquierdo -> empático), por lo que luego hace el comentario sobre la raya del cabello.

No es algo propio del idioma español, podría estar en cualquier lengua y tener el mismo sentido.

Comment: Vale, gracias. Interesante el articulo, de todas maneras, no me habia occurido antes.

Answer (score 1):

La verdad es que, como las fotos del vínculo de lenguaje corporal que colocaste, es la forma de peinarse. Sin embargo en el artículo del ciclista es algo metafórico, haciendo referencia exclusivamente al párrafo anterior.  De hecho, si buscas fotos de David Brailsford verás que está rapado.